# Qual método usar para marcar checkbox de um resultado de busca ao BD feita em ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Preciso marcar checkboxs para uma página de edição de formulários, os valores estão salvos em uma tabela onde os checkboxs que foram marcados no cadastro foram armazenados, porém não sei como puxar esses resultados e deixar marcados os mesmos campos página de edição, tratando cada cliente geraria muito transtorno pois as buscas são feitas via ajax o que dificulta um pouco pois meu conhecimento é maior no php.
Os resultados são gerados no php através de json_encode

Estrutura do BD

```
CREATE TABLE produtos (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_cliente INT(6) NOT NULL,
id_produto INT(6) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Estrutura do Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',        
    dataType: 'json',   
    url: produtos.php',
    data:{id:idcliente},
    success: function(result){

    //como colocar o resultado da busca aqui

      }
    }
});
```

Estrutura do PHP

```
<?php

require('conn/conn.php');

$cliente = $_POST['id'];

$qryprodutos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM produtos where id_cliente=$cliente");
$num = $qryprodutos->num_rows;

if($num > 0){
    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryprodutos)){
        $imprime[] = array("produto"=>$resultado['id_produto'];);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar os dados de volta para o cliente podes usar `echo json_encode($imprime);`. Assim envias um JSON de volta.

Um exemplo no PHP seria:

```
$arr[] = array('a' => true);
$arr[] = array('b' => true);
$arr[] = array('c' => false);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

que vai enviar `[{"a":true},{"b":true},{"c":false}]` para o JavaScript.

Depois, no JavaScript/jQuery podes fazer:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: produtos.php,
    data: {
        id: idcliente
    },
    success: function(result) {
        result.forEach(function(obj){
            var id = Object.keys(obj)[0];
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            el.checked = obj[id];
        });
    }
});
```

Foi um exemplo, se não conseguires implementar junta mais dados à pergunta para ajudar-mos mais.